# How to create a color picker with paper.js?

Tags: javascript, color-picker, paperjs

I've been trying to create a color picker for my drawing app for changing the brush color in paper.js, but I'm a bit lost. I used a script to create 3 HSL wheels from the paper.js library examples and they're activated by clicking on a circle in the top left corner. So far it looks like this: [HSLwheels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXWEj.png).
Does anyone know how it could be possible to read the color value from those wheels, or any other way to create a color picker with paperscript?

```
var viewColorWheel = 'true';

function showWheel() {
    var steps = {
        hue: 100,
        saturation: 20,
        lightness: 3
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < steps.lightness; i++) {
        var radius = view.size.width / steps.lightness * 0.45;
        var offset = new Point(view.size.width / steps.lightness, 0);
        var position = view.bounds.leftCenter + offset * (i + 0.5);
        var lightness = 1 - (i + 1) / (steps.lightness + 1);
        createWheel(position, radius, steps, lightness);
    };
}

function createWheel(center, radius, steps, lightness) {
    
    var hUnit = 360 / steps.hue;
    for (var h = 0; h < steps.hue; h++) {
        var hue = h * hUnit;
        var vector = new Point({
            angle: hue - 90,
            length: radius
        });
        pathC = new Path(new Point(), vector.rotate(hUnit / 2));
        pathC.closed = true;
        pathC.arcTo(vector, vector.rotate(hUnit / -2));
        pathC.position += center;
        var colors = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < steps.saturation; i++) {
            var saturation = i / steps.saturation;
            var color = { hue: hue, saturation: saturation, lightness: lightness };
            colors.push(color);
        }
        var gradient = new Gradient(colors, true);
        var from = center;
        var to = center + vector;
        var gradientColor = new Color(gradient, from, to);
        pathC.fillColor = pathC.strokeColor = gradientColor;
    }
}

var strokeColorButton = new Path.Circle({
    center: [40, 80],
    radius: 15,
    fillColor: strokeColor
});

strokeColorButton.onClick = function(event) {
    //strokeColorButton.radius = 40;
    console.log(viewColorWheel);
    if (viewColorWheel == 'true') {
        console.log(viewColorWheel);
        showWheel();
       viewColorWheel = 'false';
        //colorWheelLayer.activate()
    } else {
        viewColorWheel = 'true';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to paper.js and learning through StackOverflow and tutorials. I am struggling more than I am developing. :D
I've created a simple color picker tool. I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for hopefully it might help.

`

```js
var paintColor = "red";

    const changeColor = (color) => {
        paintColor = color;
    }    
    paper.install(window);
    window.onload = function () {
        paper.setup('drawCanvas');

        var tool = new Tool();
        var path;

        tool.onMouseDown = function (event,  strokeColor = paintColor) {
            path = new Path({
                center: event.path,
                strokeColor: strokeColor,
                strokeSize: 2
            });
            // path.add(event.point);
        }

        tool.onMouseDrag = function (event) {
            path.add(event.point);
        }
    }
  
    function clearCanvas() {
        paper.project.activeLayer.removeChildren();
        paper.view.draw();
    }
```

```css
    html,body{
    height: 100%;
    }
    body{
    font: 20px sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    }
    canvas [resize]{
    flex: 1;
    border: 4px solid rgb(75, 75, 75);
    width: 100%;
    }  
    .tools {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;        
    top:1%;
    left: 40%;
    position: fixed;
    align-items:center;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;       
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color Picker with PaperJs</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.15/paper-full.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="tools">
        <div class="color">
            <label for="pen-color">Color</label>
            <input type="color" id="pen-color" value="#000" onclick="changeColor(this.value);">
        </div>    

        <div class="clear">
            <label>Clear Canvas</label>
            <button onclick="clearCanvas()">
                Clear
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

<canvas id="drawCanvas" resize></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

One technique could be to rasterize the wheels using [item.rasterize()](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#rasterize) method that you created and use the [raster.getPixel()](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#getpixel-point) method to pick a color on click.

Here's a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) based on your code, demonstrating a way to do it.

```js
function showWheel() {
    var steps = {
        hue: 100,
        saturation: 20,
        lightness: 3
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < steps.lightness; i++) {
        var radius = view.size.width / steps.lightness * 0.45;
        var offset = new Point(view.size.width / steps.lightness, 0);
        var position = view.bounds.leftCenter + offset * (i + 0.5);
        var lightness = 1 - (i + 1) / (steps.lightness + 1);
        createWheel(position, radius, steps, lightness);
    }
}

function createWheel(center, radius, steps, lightness) {

    var hUnit = 360 / steps.hue;
    for (var h = 0; h < steps.hue; h++) {
        var hue = h * hUnit;
        var vector = new Point({
            angle: hue - 90,
            length: radius
        });
        pathC = new Path(new Point(), vector.rotate(hUnit / 2));
        pathC.closed = true;
        pathC.arcTo(vector, vector.rotate(hUnit / -2));
        pathC.position += center;
        var colors = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < steps.saturation; i++) {
            var saturation = i / steps.saturation;
            var color = { hue: hue, saturation: saturation, lightness: lightness };
            colors.push(color);
        }
        var gradient = new Gradient(colors, true);
        var from = center;
        var to = center + vector;
        var gradientColor = new Color(gradient, from, to);
        pathC.fillColor = pathC.strokeColor = gradientColor;
    }
}

showWheel();

// Rasterize the wheels so that we can pick color.
const raster = project.activeLayer.rasterize();
// Create a circle showing the picked color.
const circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.bounds.topCenter,
    radius: 80,
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeColor: 'black'
});
// Show instructions
new PointText({
    content: 'Click on the wheels to pick a color',
    point: view.center + [0, -200],
    justification: 'center'
});

// On mouse down...
function onMouseDown(event) {
    // ...if the point is part of the raster...
    if (raster.hitTest(event.point)) {
        // ...convert it to local coordinates.
        const localPoint = raster.globalToLocal(event.point).add(
            raster.bounds.width / 2,
            raster.bounds.height / 2
        );
        // Use it to pick the color.
        const color = raster.getPixel(localPoint);
        // Update the demonstration circle color.
        circle.fillColor = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Looks like a nice solution, however I've already ended up using spectrum.js and javascript alongside paperscript, because I turned out to be the easiest way